# User input an array from Client and Server calculator it (on C#)

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm a newbie and I'm having a small Socket programming exercise.

User input an array from Client and Server calculator it ( + ,* ) and send to client total

This my code but it doesn' run correctly.

My code

Server.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace sv
 {
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2016);
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Bind(iep);
        server.Listen(10);
        Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
        Socket client = server.Accept();
        Console.WriteLine("Accept {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                string s = "Welcome";
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);


                           while (true)
                           {
                               data = new byte[1024];
                               int recv = client.Receive(data);
                               string c = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                               Console.WriteLine("Client: {0}", c);
                           }



                        byte[] gdata = new byte[1024];
                        byte[] total = new byte[1024];

                        string array;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            int recv = client.Receive(gdata);
                            array = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(gdata, 0, recv);
                            Console.WriteLine("Client: {0}", array);

                            //SUM
                            int sum = 0;
                            string[] arrListStr = array.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                            for (int i = 0; i < arrListStr.Length; i++)
                            {
                                sum += Int32.Parse(arrListStr[i]);

                            }
                            array = sum.ToString();
                            total = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(array);
                            client.Send(total, total.Length,                  SocketFlags.None);
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Client

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cl
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2016);
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        client.Connect(iep);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int recv = client.Receive(data);
        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        Console.WriteLine("From Server : {0}", s);
        string input;
        while (true)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            data = new byte[1024];
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }

        data = new byte[1024];
        recv = client.Receive(data);
        s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        Console.WriteLine("From Server : {0}, s");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
}
```

Pls help me fix it. Thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

change your code like below, it will give you the sum
pass values from client as comma separated like 12,13

server

```
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2016);
        Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        server.Bind(iep);
        server.Listen(10);
        Console.WriteLine("waiting...");
        Socket client = server.Accept();
        Console.WriteLine("Accept {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        string s = "Welcome";
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);




        byte[] gdata = new byte[1024];
        byte[] total = new byte[1024];

        string array;
        while (true)
        {
            int recv = client.Receive(gdata);
            array = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(gdata, 0, recv);
            Console.WriteLine("Client: {0}", array);

            //SUM
            int sum = 0;
            string[] arrListStr = array.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < arrListStr.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += Int32.Parse(arrListStr[i]);

            }
            array = sum.ToString();
            total = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(array);
            client.Send(total, total.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }
```

client

```
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 2016);
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        client.Connect(iep);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int recv = client.Receive(data);
        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
        Console.WriteLine("From Server : {0}", s);
        string input;


        while (true)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            data = new byte[1024];
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);

           // data = new byte[1024];
            recv = client.Receive(data);
            s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            Console.WriteLine("From Server : {0}", s);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```